# Incrementing name attribute of text field

Tags: jquery, html, paypal

Ok, this is an attempt to increment the name attribute of the text field.

I don't know jquery/js, so I googled around for a script, and [found one](http://websistent.com/dynamic-textbox-jquery-php/).

It works for most part, but I had to modify it a bit so that the name attribute of the text box will increment in its number, ie, `on0`, `on1`, `on2`, `on3`, etc.

Reason for that is [Paypal's optional variable](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables/): on0

This is what I have so far: [jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/zwvkqydx/)

But if you look at the textboxes via firebug, you can see that the first name attribute is `on0`, but then it jumps to `on2` without `on1`.

Why?

I think I need to keep the increments in an orderly fashion, or Paypal may not accept the optional variable. And they are needed.

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a quite simple fix. In your box_html variable (line 4), I decreased the value with 1.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('.my-form .add-box').click(function() {
    var n = $('.text-box').length + 1;
    var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"><label for="box' + n + '">Box <span class="box-number">' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" name="on' + (n - 1) + '" value="" id="box' + n + '" /> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>');
    box_html.hide();
    $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
    box_html.fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
  });

  $('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function() {
    $(this).parent().css('background-color', '#FF6C6C');
    $(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
      $(this).remove();
      $('.box-number').each(function(index) {
        $(this).text(index + 1);
      });
    });
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my-form">
  <form role="form" method="post">
    <p class="text-box">
      <label for="box1">Box <span class="box-number">1</span>
      </label>
      <input type="text" name="on0" value="" id="box1" />
      <a class="add-box" href="#">Add More</a>
    </p>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </p>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: hey, thank you. Using your answer. Thank you for taking the time to respond.

Comment: No problem at all ;). If you need help, just ask.

Comment: definitely will! =) I have several more issues to sort out, but trying to do  it step by step. Being slow in other words.

Answer (score -1):

i've made some changes on your js code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$('.my-form .add-box').click(function(){
```

> var n = $('.text-box').length -1 + 1;

```
    var box_html = $('<p class="text-box"><label for="box' + n + '">Box <span class="box-number">' + n + '</span></label> <input type="text" name="on' + n + '" value="" id="box' + n + '" /> <a href="#" class="remove-box">Remove</a></p>');
    box_html.hide();
    $('.my-form p.text-box:last').after(box_html);
    box_html.fadeIn('slow');
    return false;
});

$('.my-form').on('click', '.remove-box', function(){
$(this).parent().css( 'background-color', '#FF6C6C' );
$(this).parent().fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).remove();
    $('.box-number').each(function(index){
```

> $(this).text( index );

```
    });
});
return false;
```

});
});

Comment: hey, thank you. Not using your answer, but I appreciate you taking the time to respond. =)